# multiple definition of main, first defined here in devc++

Tags: c++

I'm just a beginner in c++ I'm using devC++. I have two separate files in a project but when I run the second file it gives an error message:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main' first defined here).
```

Can you please explain me clearly in details what to change how to do it.

Sorry for repeating the question because of my lack of understanding if there is any answer in details already please provide the link.

These are my two files:

prblm2.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const double artificial_sweetner=0.001;
    double mouse_weight, friend_weight, die, number_of_soda_pop; 
    cout<<"type in the weight of the mouse and your freinds target weight"<<endl;
    cin>>mouse_weight>>friend_weight;

    while (mouse_weight>0 && friend_weight>0)
    {
        die=(friend_weight/mouse_weight)*artificial_sweetner;
        number_of_soda_pop=die/artificial_sweetner;
        cout<<"the number of soda your freind can drink is "<<number_of_soda_pop<<endl;
        cout<<"type in the weight of the mouse and your freinds target weight"<<endl;
        cin>>mouse_weight>>friend_weight;
    }

}
```

test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(i=1;i<10;i++)
        {
            for(i=1;i<10;i++)
            {
                cout<<"*"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't have two mains....

Comment: i know if i remove the main from the second file it doesn't work

Comment: I’ve downvoted the question because you already know the answer (“put it in separate project”) and didn’t give a reasons why it doesn’t work for you (“but I don't want to” is hardly a reason).

Comment: @ Dzmitry Kushnarou some time you want to keep your files organized You don't want files to get mixed  between two different projects

Comment: @Tasif Projects exist for organising your code. One project contains code for one program. If you are creating two programs (which is what you’re doing), you should create two projects.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have two `main` functions. The standard disallows such program. The solution is to have exactly one `main`.

For example:

This program is not OK, because there are too few `main` functions:

```
void foo(){}
```

This program is not OK, because there are too many `main` functions:

```
int main(){}
int main(){}
```

This program is well formed, and has just the right number of `main` functions:

```
int main(){}
```

Comment: so should i remove the main from the second file if do that  
the program does not run.

Comment: @Tasif are you sure that it doesn't run? How did you verify that?

Comment: @ user2079303 C:\Users\User\Documents\C++\prob solving\programming projects\test.cpp [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'for' i removed the int main() and the braces.

Comment: @Tasif that is not a problem with running the program. That is a compilation error. You cannot just remove the function prototype, and the braces. You have to remove all the lines in between as well.

Comment: so just tell me how the code is going to be for the second file and thank u 4 ur patience

Comment: @Tasif you can remove the second file entirely.